# Is it normal for Ubuntu to take a long time to shut down after running the boot-repair program?

Tags: boot, reboot, boot-repair

Several months ago, I installed Lubuntu alongside Windows 7 on my laptop. I decided to uninstall Lubuntu and install Linux Mint, and so I used EasyBCD to write the MBR for Windows 7/Windows Vista and boot directly into Windows 7 at startup. I then deleted the 2 volumes which contained the data for my Lubuntu installation (which I originally created by partitioning my second hard drive), deleted the partition, and I extended my second hard drive with the free partition. This process had worked for me when I was uninstalling Lubuntu from another laptop several months ago, and I was sure this would work again without any hitches.

When I restarted my computer, however, I ran into a missing device error with grub. I didn't really know how to fix it, so I used a LiveUSB of Ubuntu in order to use the boot-repair tool (by running the Try Ubuntu option and downloading boot-repair) to regain access to Windows. I ran it, and it said that the boot was successfully repaired and it was safe to reboot. I did as such, but Ubuntu took a long time to shutdown, so I thought it must have been some error and I did a force shutdown.

After turning on the laptop, it said that bootmgr was missing, and the only option given was to restart the computer, and after restarting 5 times, it still said the same message. I used the LiveUSB again to run the boot-repair tool to repair the boot, and I am currently waiting on Ubuntu to reboot. Is it normal for Ubuntu to take this long to reboot, or is this an error?

Here is the paste from the boot-repair if it is of any help: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5842294/

I'm sorry if I left any information out, and I'll try my best to provide any information about the problem if needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I then deleted the 2 volumes which contained the data for my Lubuntu installation (which I originally created by partitioning my second hard drive), deleted the partition, and I extended my second hard drive with the free partition.

You had to be sure that EasyBCD wrote Windows loader directly to first disk's MBR, because for me it always writes loader to partition where Windows is installed. After the first reboot you had GRUB MBR on first disk, Windows MBR on second and no partitions where first could find boot configuration. Sad. And after boot repair you have the same situation because this tool apparently does not recover deleted volumes, it only fixes typical boot problems. To boot Windows, you should make the second disk first in boot sequence or use Windows Repair or Installation Media to fix boot problems, because Ubuntu now nas no deal with it.

Comment: Booting from the second hard drive worked, but within EasyBCD, but how do I make sure that it writes the Windows loader directly to the first disk's MBR?

Comment: Also, will writing Windows loader directly to the first disk's MBR fix the issue with Windows not booting from the first hard drive?

Comment: If you have system on the first hard disk and only data on second, you can temporarily disable second in BIOS/EFI, then run Windows Repair CD, which you can make when you have Windows running, or simply run Windows Installation media (if you have it) and choose fix boot problems. And it seems to me that EasyBCD has no option to choose right drive, so you can not rely on it.