# Long load time for kernel after Boot repair

Tags: boot, kernel, time

After a necessairy boot repair, the kernel load time is significantly longer than normal: 34s.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/s45GGcf22B
I don't know how to fix that.

about:
[Long kernel load time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164632/long-kernel-load-time)
the Intel Speed Step, on or off gave me both 34s for the kernel to load.

I don't understand this solution well:
[Is it normal for Ubuntu to take a long time to shut down after running the boot-repair program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316147/is-it-normal-for-ubuntu-to-take-a-long-time-to-shut-down-after-running-the-boot)

My grub menu seems to be on my Windows SSD and my Ubuntu on an other SSD.

I had to repair the boot since I accidently pulled out a data cable of one of my SSD drives.
Luckily, I have access to my Windows and my Ubuntu.

Here is my startup script in the Grub Customizer for Ubuntu, causing the slow start:

```
Here is the script I found in the Grub customizer to launch my Ubuntu:

recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  c1d84984-8159-4a32-bf22-a30e1d0f33fe
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c1d84984-8159-4a32-bf22-a30e1d0f33fe
fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-128-generic root=UUID=c1d84984-8159-4a32-bf22-a30e1d0f33fe ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-128-generic
```

Comment: Some things to check & links to even more. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster After abnormal shutdown, full fsck often required for ext4 partition(s) and chkdsk from Windows on NTFS partitions.

Comment: I don't see any need to check a full filecheck because there was no data connection to the disconnected partition. I just need to know how to launch. My Ubuntu to launch is at:     /dev/sdb1.

Comment: Do you have the old BIOS/MBR configuration, not new UEFI with gpt partitioning? Unless old system better to use UEFI/gpt. Grub Customizer replaces grub scripts with its own proxy scripts. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Some more info: systemd-analyze time 
Startup finished in 6.033s (firmware) + 5.200s (loader) + 34.282s (kernel) + 4.449s (userspace) = 49.966s
graphical.target reached after 4.262s in userspace

grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.20

Comment: I dont know which configuration.  So, I have to set root to "set root='hd1,ppa1'" ?

Comment: Without seeing Summary Report from Boot-Repair, difficult to make any specific recommendations.

Comment: You need to click the paste hyperlink to see the summary of the boot repair!
I launched now in recovery mode and this took a lot of time, abnormal long in my opinion:   /scripts/local-premount

Comment: Boot-Repair reinstalled grub without error. Are you booting ubuntu entry in UEFI boot mode? Report did not show /etc/fstab. Do you have any entries that are not valid? What video card chip? From very first comment, did you change quiet splash to noplymouth? Then you see boot process and where it may be slow. Also same into in logs.

Comment: UEFI Boot mode? Maybe. I'll check /etc/fstab and see what I find there. I don't have video card fysicly. I don't know if I changed splash to noplymouth. I saw boot process during recovery mode, which I still can do. I just need to have a way to tell the pc where to launch my Ubuntu at that boot menu.

Comment: I found this message during startup: "MODSIGN: couldn't get UEFI DB list."

Comment: When I enter /etc/fstab in the file explorer, I arrive at my personal home spot.

Comment: Try: `cat /etc/fstab` if in your install. If in live installer and want to see version in your install, you have to mount it and then include that in your path. Is UEFI Secure Boot on? MODSIGN is related to Secure Boot, but may be trying to load a video driver or WiFi driver that is not signed, you have to manually sign any proprietary drivers. some systems have other settings also besides UEFI Secure Boot which could be "Windows" or "Other" Change UEFI settings from custom to standard
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380700 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407705

Comment: I don't know if UEFI secure boot is on.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PcTANbg1

Comment: Since mounting ESP, you have UEFI install. Did you comment out swap and manually create a new swap file? I did that with one install and it required multiple commands. Almost easier to do new install and erase swap partition before install.

Comment: I have 8 Gb RAM. I don't need a swap partition. My bios indicates launching possibility for LEGACY and UEFI.

Comment: Since you have UEFI, do not turn on or boot any Legecy/CSM/BIOS type settings. new installer now uses swap file. I had an old one and using Something Else clicked/changed swap to Do  Not USE and it installed with swap file.

Comment: Isn't there any solution?

Comment: My motherboard would only boot in UEFI mode with UEFI only setting. UEFI or CSM always wanted to boot in BIOS mode.

Comment: I have only UEFI active at bios. Maybe I'll reinstall Ubuntu after an upgrade of my hardware.

Comment: Are there any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you go thru all the options in comment 1 link? And what results did each change give?

Comment: I went thorough the necessary options in comment 1. One UUID doesn't seem to have "noatime" but I don't know how to change. Do you need to see the outputs of "lsblk -o name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint,uuid | egrep -v "^loop"" and "cat /etc/fstab"?

Comment: I use noatime for SSD and relatime for HDD partiitons. `sudo nano /etc/fstab` No spaces in parameter & must be spelled correctly. Parameters I have for / (root) `noatime,errors=remount-ro` But that should not change boot time much. It is more for write time.

Comment: For me, it's a giant blur. What's the difference between EFI and UEFI? It's too complex. :(

Comment: History, version. Intel created EFI as new improved replacement to BIOS. Then Apple adopted it for Intel based Macs. Intel turned it over to UEFI and EFI became UEFI v1. Microsoft adopted UEFI in 2012 and required vendors to install all new systems with UEFI with gpt partition. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

Comment: In the past with those old SATA HDDs, I was able to force the boot by discoupling one. Apparently, I can't use that trick with my SSD's.

Comment: Can this help: http://roelaro21.twentyone.axc.nl/press/UEFI DB list not found.png?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:
[Boot hangs for 30 seconds at "Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034359/boot-hangs-for-30-seconds-at-begin-running-scripts-local-premount)
THe system searched for a swap file, which I don't have. I don't need a swap for my 8 GB!